# In what circumstances are Docker projects rebuilt?

Tags: .net, docker

I have built an application, which contains many Docker containers to learn more about Docker in my spare time.  On my Mac, the Docker projects are never rebuilt i.e. I debug the application in Visual Studio 2019 and the application (webpage) appears immediately every time.

On my Windows PC, the application sometimes appears immediately as per the Mac.  However, I sometimes see this in the output window:

> Building mvcwebapp
>
> Building service1
>
> Building service2
>
> Building service3
>
> etc

It takes ages to build (over two hours).  I have two questions:

1. Why does it take so long to build? 
   The images exist - it just seems to take so long to rebuild the containers.
2. In what circumstances are Docker projects rebuilt (specifically on a Windows PC if this is relevant)?

My first thoughts are when:

1. Docker is restarted 
   and/or
2. When Visual Studio is restarted
   and/or
3. When PC is restarted
   and/or
4. When files are deleted on the PC

However, my testing has not proven anything conclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the reason for this is because I was using the default `.dockerignore` file.  I changed the contents of .dockerignore to this:

```
.dockerignore
.env
.git
.gitignore
.vs
.vscode
docker-compose*.yml
docker-compose.dcproj
*.sln
*.md
hosts
LICENSE
*.testsettings
vsts-docs
test
ServiceFabric
readme
k8s
img
docs
deploy
Components
cli-windows
cli-mac
cli-linux
**/bin/
**/obj/
**/node_modules/
**/bower_components/
**/wwwroot/lib/*
global.json
**/appsettings.localhost.json
src/Web/WebSPA/wwwroot/
packages/
csproj-files/
test-results/
TestResults/
src/Mobile/
```

The build time then reduced from several hours to a few seconds.

I was planning to delete this question, however I see lots of similar questions on the Docker website where there are no answers.  Therefore I have answered here with the hope it will help someone.